# IntelliJ Editor Tabs: Last Recently Used

Tags: intellij-idea

in my new team we're using IntelliJ and there is one Eclipse feature I miss very dearly:

In a usual situation I have like 20-30 files open im my editor, but there is like 2-3 that I jump around most of the time. Eclipse supported this perfectly by always having the last recently used files in my tabs open and only the rarely used ones in the overflow. IntelliJ follows the exactly opposite paradigm: The last recently used files are always in the overflow and the tabs are useless.

Is there any way to make this more comfortable? I currently have them ordered alphabetically so I can at least find them in the overflow. Unchecking that makes it even more terriblester.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Feel free to vote for https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-151642 to see this option added to the IDE editor tab settings.

In the meantime, you can use the **Recent Files** (`Ctrl+E`) list, as well as the **Recent Locations** switcher (`Ctrl+Shift+E`).

More information on navigating between recent locations and changes:

- https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/Navigation_and_Search__Navigating_to_Recent_Locations.html
- https://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2013/02/navigating-between-files-in-the-ide-best-practices

Answer (score 0):

I was so annoyed by the lack of this feature that I spent a day learning how to write IntelliJ plugins, and created one that keeps tabs sorted by most recently used.

You can find it here: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/21356-recent-tab-order